# Uploading Layers on ArcGIS Online displays unexpected line?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, buffer, cyclone

I digitized a cyclone track on ArcGIS as a polyline. Then i created a buffer of 100 km using the buffer tool. My parameters when using the buffer are:

- Distance- Linear Unit of 100km
- Side Type- Full
- End Type- Round
- Method- Planar
- Dissolve Type- None
- Coordinate System- Projected (Fiji Map Grid 1976)

Then i wanted to upload it on ArcGIS online. I used the Add layer from file tool. The buffers werent showing so i had to play around with the visibility range of each feature. But when the buffers finally appear, it has a line at the very bottom as shown on the picture below marked blue.

[image]

I dont know where that came from.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you select the Polygon, can you identify how many features there are? What if you run the dissolve with the Dissolve Type as "ALL"? Just following my regular fault checking thought process. I just went to the site in GE, I see that line that is there looks very similar to the Anti-Meridian. Are you sure that Line is not just a graphic representation of the 180 degree longitude?

Comment: The line is almost certainly the 180 degree anti-meridian as @KeaganAllan mentioned. Are you sure the coordinate system is Fiji 1976? I can't find anything about that coordinate system. However, [Fiji 1986](https://epsg.io/3460) looks like it should work. Or better yet, use the [Albers Equal Area Projection](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/fiji-albers-equal-area-conic-wgs84/).

Comment: Hi sorry it should be Fiji 1986. I have dissolved the line and i feel its the 180 degree Anti-meridian. Is there a way for it not to show?